# How do I add an OR to an existing string filter in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, filter, activeadmin

I need to be able to search by multiple terms in a string filter for ActiveAdmin 0.4.0.

e.g.

```
filter :city, :as => :string
```

How can I change this to be able to search for terms such as 'New York' OR 'Los Angeles' OR 'Detroit' ?

Comment: Hm, I doubt that you'll be able to do this :)

Answer (score 1):

you want that:

```
filter :city, :as => :string, :match => 'New York', :or => :match => 'Los Angeles', :or => :match => 'Detroit'

‘match’ will check if a field, when turned into a string, matches a given regular expression.

‘smatch’ works the same but only accepts fields that are strings.
```

more info [here](http://ruote.rubyforge.org/exp/filter.html)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I don't think this applies to the ActiveAdmin implementation.  It won't allow me to access the :match option.